# Is postURL no longer supported?

Tags: profile

We have recently upgraded from 4.4 to 4.7.3 and are now experiencing an issue with one of our profiles. It seems that the civi will no longer use the postURL we are passing to it in an html form. I don't see any release notes saying this was removed and I am kind of at a loss of what could be causing this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

David

Comment: is this for a standalone profile, or one within a contribution page etc? also why did this get tagged with custom-templates? other than SE requires at least one tag and you may not have found a more suitable one ;-)

Comment: Sorry I clicked the wrong tag.

This is a stand alone profile that is basically used for a sign up form. It used to work with postURL=xxxxx in the post request to civi.

Comment: What did postURL do that doesn't work now?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Having the same issue here with HTML form from another site.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about a profile where you've copied the HTML Snippet and pasted it onto another site.  If so, you should be aware that the necessary code does change periodically between major versions.

Thankfully, the answer is pretty straightforward: just generate the HTML Snippet all over again.  Go to **Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles** and select **More > HTML Form Snippet** next to your profile.  Copy the HTML and paste it into your other page.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the postURL to work on HTML snippets either, but setting a redirect URL in the actual profile settings worked ok.